# How to use Case after using Inner Join ON

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, inner-join

How do I use a case expression after the last inner join ON?

```
Create View v_classroom
AS
SELECT A.roomcode,A.roomname,A.deviceID,
B.occupancy,B.Temperature,B.localtime,
C.classend,C.classstart,C.subject
From devicemessage b
inner join device A ON b.deviceID =A.deviceId
inner join classtimetable C on A.roomcode= c.roomid
//i want to use case statement here
```

Comment: What should this ```CASE``` do? You can add it anywhere, where an expression is expected

Comment: @LonelyBat, What you want to add in case statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want the case statement to do.

For example, say you want to return a value based on the occupancy. In this case, your case statement would need to be part of the `select` clause.

```
Create View v_classroom
AS
SELECT 
     A.roomcode
    ,A.roomname
    ,A.deviceID
    ,B.occupancy
    ,case     -- This returns a new column 'Occupancy_result' with the case statement result
        when occupancy >= 5 then 'ROOM FULL'
        when occupancy = 0 then 'ROOM EMPTY'
        else 'ROOM PARTIALLY FULL'
        end as Occupancy_Result 
    ,B.Temperature
    ,B.localtime
    ,C.classend
    ,C.classstart
    ,C.subject
From devicemessage b
    inner join device A 
        ON b.deviceID = A.deviceId
    inner join classtimetable C 
        on A.roomcode = c.roomid
```

If you want to *filter* your results based on their values, a better choice would be a `where` statement after the `join` clauses.

```
Create View v_classroom
AS
SELECT 
     A.roomcode
    ,A.roomname
    ,A.deviceID
    ,B.occupancy
    ,B.Temperature
    ,B.localtime
    ,C.classend
    ,C.classstart
    ,C.subject
From devicemessage b
    inner join device A 
        ON b.deviceID = A.deviceId
    inner join classtimetable C 
        on A.roomcode = c.
where occupancy <= 5    -- This filters out any results that do not meet the condition
```

If neither of these solutions quite meet your needs on their own, a combination of the two may be the answer. You can use a case statement in the `select` clause and then filter the resulting values in the `where` statement.